# Applying a set of operations across several data frames in r

Tags: r

I've been learning R for my project and have been unable to google a solution to my current problem.

I have ~ 100 csv files and need to perform an exact set of operations across them. I've read them in as separate objects (which I assume is probably improper r style) but I've been unable to write a function that can loop through.  Each csv is a dataframe that contain information, including a column with dates in decimal year form.  I need to create 2 new columns containing year and day of year.  I've figured out how to do it manually I would like to find a way to automate the process.  Here's what I've been doing:

```
#setup
library(lubridate)  #Used to check for leap years
df.00 <- data.frame( site = seq(1:10), date = runif(10,1980,2000 ))


#what I need done

df.00$doy <- NA  # make an empty column which I'm going to place the day of the year
df.00$year <- floor(df.00$date) # grabs the year from the date column
df.00$dday <- df.00$date - df.00$year # get the year fraction. intermediate step.

# multiply the fraction year by 365 or 366 if it's a leap year to give me the day of the year
df.00$doy[which(leap_year(df.00$year))] <- round(df.00$dday[which(leap_year(df.00$year))] * 366)
df.00$doy[which(!leap_year(df.00$year))] <- round(df.00$dday[which(!leap_year(df.00$year))] * 365)
```

The above, while inelegant, does what I would like it to.  However, I need to do this to the other data frames, df.01 - df.99.  So far I've been unable to place it in a function or for loop.  If I place it into a function:

```
funtest <- function(x) {
    x$doy <- NA
}
```

funtest(df.00) does nothing.  Which is what I would expect from my understanding of how functions work in r but if I wrap it up in a for loop:

```
for(i in c(df.00)) { 
    i$doy <- NA }
```

I get "In i$doy <- NA : Coercing LHS to a list" several times which tells me that the loop isn't treat the dataframe as a single unit but perhaps looking at each column in the frame.
I would really appreciate some insight on what I should be doing.  I feel that I could have solved this easily using bash and awk but I would like to be less incompetent using r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the most efficient and direct way is to use a list.

1. Put all of your CSV's into one folder
2. grab a list of the files in that folder
   eg:  `files <- dir('path/to/folder', full.names=TRUE)`
3. iterativly read in all those files into a list of `data.frame`s
   eg: `df.list <- lapply(files, read.csv, <additional args>)`
4. apply your function iteratively over each data.frame
   eg: `lapply(df.list, myFunc, <additional args>)`

---

Since your df's are already loaded, and they have nice convenient names, you can grab them easily using the following:

```
nms     <- c(paste0("df.0", 0:9), paste0("df.", 10:99))
df.list <- lapply(nms, get)
```

Then take everything you have in the `#what I need done` portion and put inside a function, eg:

```
myFunc <- function(DF) {

   # what you want done to a single DF
return(DF)
}
```

And then `lapply` accordingly

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list, myFunc)
```

---

#### On a separate notes, regarding functions:

The reason your `funTest` "does nothing" is that it you are not having it return anything. That is to say, it *is* doing something, but when it finishes doing that, *then* it does "nothing".

You need to include a `return(.)` statement in the function. Alternatively, the output of last line of the function, if not assigned to an object, will be used as the return value -- but this last sentence is only loosely true and hence one needs to be cautious. The cleanest option (in my opinion) is to use `return(.)`

---

#### regarding the `for` loop over the `data.frame`

As you observed, using `for (i in someDataFrame) {...}` iterates over the **columns** of the `data.frame`.

You can iterate over the rows using `apply`:

```
apply(myDF, MARGIN=1, function(x) { x$doy <- ...; return(x) } ) # dont forget to return
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I feel almost foolish for omitting the return(x) as that solved my problem.  I took your advice and read everything into a list.  lappy seems like a more elegant solution than my for loops.  I would upvote you but I apparently lack the  required rep.