# lapply set of functions across multiple dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a set of functions I need to apply to several dataframes. I want to use the lapply function instead of for() loops.

```
#sample data frame
id    lastpage    attribute_2
1          20            232
2          8             232
3          6             129
4          20           1271
5          20            129
6          20             74
```

The functions work when I apply it to one dataframe at a time. It basically removes duplicates (based on attribute_2) with the lowest values for variable 'lastpage':

```
 df <- df[order(df$attribute_2, -df$lastpage),]
 df <- df[!duplicated(df$attribute_2),]
```

When I try to (l)apply this function to several dataframes, nothing seems to have changed when I call the dataframe. Intuitively I think I am messing up something when calling df, but I am not sure what:

```
df.list <- list(df0, df1, df2, df3)
myFunc <- function(df) {
df <- df[order(df$attribute_2, -df$lastpage),]
df <- df[!duplicated(df$attribute_2),]
return(df)
}
df.list <- lapply(df.list, FUN = myFunc)
```

Your help is much appreciated!
I have looked at all similar previous questions on lapply functions, specifically this one: [Applying a set of operations across several data frames in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115745/applying-a-set-of-operations-across-several-data-frames-in-r) 
I am probably making a very obvious mistake, but I just can't find it.

EDIT: thanks everyone for the help
For anyone wondering what code I exactly use now:

```
df.list <- list(df0, df1, df2, df3)
myFunc <- function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$attribute_2, -x$lastpage),]
  x <- x[!duplicated(x$attribute_2),]
}
df.list2 <- lapply(df.list, myFunc)

df2_c<-df.list2[[3]]
```

Comment: Please make your example more reproducible by adding sample data.

Comment: lapply applies on vector, not on lists, even if the parameter is called 'list' .. maybe you can try with a vector .. If you can't make a vector of dataframes, you'll have to work with a vector of strings (the names of your df) and then in the function use eval to make some change .. also, inside a function it's not obvious that you can change a global object, so try with "<<-" instead of "<-" .. good luck !

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Lists *are* vectors in R. `lapply` works just fine with lists. Furthermore, `<<-` is also inappropriate here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : yes, you're certainly right .. can you explain more about "<<-" ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington `<<-` performs assignment in a parent environment but OP doesn’t want this (it would create, and repeatedly override, a single variable called `df` in the global environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example does what you intend to do:

```
set.seed(314)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
                 y = sample(1:10, size = 50, replace = TRUE))

df.list <- list(df,df,df,df)

lapply(df.list,nrow)

testfunction <- function(data){
  data[!duplicated(data$x),]
}

lapply(df.list, testfunction)
```

I think there is something wrong with your function. I noticed that you reference column `email` which is not in your dataframe.

It is also advisable to rename the variables that are used inside the function, so you don't reference global variables.

And as Konrad said in the other answer, your original dataframes stayed the same, so call them for example as follows:

```
df.list2 <- lapply(df.list, testfunction)

df.list2[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you Wietze314. I have corrected the email variable, it should be attribute_2. I have tried your suggestions and it seems to have worked! One follow-up question: I would like to use the datasets from the new list (df.list2) for further analysis. But when I call for example df2, I get the old dataframe. Whereas when I call for df.list2[[3]], I get the dataframe without duplicates and nicely ordered. How do I now use the dataframes from this new list?

Comment: As you mentioned, use them in another lapply function or call them using `df.list[[1]]`, for example `numberofrows <- nrow(df.list[[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably works as expected but you’re assigning its result to `df.list`, not to the original data.frames. The list contains *copies* of these, so they would never get modified. This is intentional, and the desired behaviour in R.

In fact, just keep working with your list of data.frames.